# Ant replace delimited tokens in property files

Tags: ant, properties

I have properties

```
environment.dir=c:\templocation
environmentconfig.dir=c:\templocation\\config
finalLocation.dir=c:\finalLocation
```

These are generated into a properties file by a set of ant scripts, with the properties file values being delimited by the system automatically.  I can't change these scripts.  So the
propFileToChange.properties =

```
environment.dir=c:\\templocation
environmentconfig.dir=c:\\templocation\\config
finalLocation.dir=c:\\finalLocation
```

I want to replace the environment.dir value in the generated file for all properties in the file with another property.  However I can't work out how to deal with the delimited text.
The result I want:

```
environment.dir=c:\\finalLocation
environmentconfig.dir=c:\\finalLocation\\config
```

I've tried:

```
<replace file="propFileToChange.properties" token="${environment.dir}" value="c:\\finalLocation" />
```

I've tried:

```
<propertyfile file="temp.properties">
    <entry key="${environment.dir}" value="c:\\finallocation"
</propertyfile>
<replace file="propFileToChange.properties" replacefilterfile="temp.properties" summary="true" />
```

The don't seem to find the token due to the contents of the property file being delimited.  So is there some way I can delimit the token before looking for it?

Answer (score 0):

The replace task is designed to replace tokens in the source file. A token normally begins and ends in @, marking the text to be replaced.

For example:

```
environment.dir=@environment.dir@
environmentconfig.dir=@environmentconfig.dir@
finalLocation.dir=@finalLocation.dir@
```

In your case the source file has no discernible tokens, but we can manufacture them as follows:

```
<copy file="propFileToChange.properties" tofile="build.properties" overwrite="true">
  <filterset begintoken="c:\\" endtoken="location">
    <filter token="temp" value="c:\\finalLocation"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

Here I'm specifying that the token "temp" begins with the string "c:\" and ends with "location". Meaning it will perform the following desired substitution.

## Example

```
├── build.properties
├── build.xml
└── propFileToChange.properties
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="replace">

  <target name="replace">
    <copy file="propFileToChange.properties" tofile="build.properties" overwrite="true">
      <filterset begintoken="c:\\" endtoken="location">
        <filter token="temp" value="c:\\finalLocation"/>
      </filterset>
    </copy>
  </target>

</project>
```

### propFileToChange.properties

```
environment.dir=c:\\templocation
environmentconfig.dir=c:\\templocation\\config
finalLocation.dir=c:\\finalLocation
```

### build.properties

```
environment.dir=c:\\finalLocation
environmentconfig.dir=c:\\finalLocation\\config
finalLocation.dir=c:\\finalLocation
```

Comment: Thanks.  So it looks like you've created a token c:\\templocation (just split it into 3 parts - same result)?
My issue is how to generate c:\\templocation from ${environment.dir} (and c:\\finalLocation from ${finalLocation.dir} ).  Note - this is a simplified example.  The actual file path is much longer and has other delimiters too, and I have 4 sets of properties to replace.